# Multiple Observations per Subject per Time-point analysis?

Tags: repeated-measures, mcnemar-test

I am having a difficult time finding an appropriate test for my analysis. Please help -

In my study I have 130 participants who were tested with a binary outcome (pass [1] /fail [0]) before and after an intervention. However, each participant was tested twice in the pre-test and twice in the post-test.

I am trying to determine if the proportion of subjects who pass is higher in the post-test. In this scenario, I think it would be best to use the McNemar's test as we have a binary outcome for a repeated measures test. However, how can I take into consideration the bias between the subjects within each time point?

For clarification: Each Subject wrote the same test twice in the pre-test and the same test twice in the post-test.

Any insight would be helpful. Please let me know if my explanation is clear.

Thanks!

Mon

Comment: You have measurements which are nested within individuals. It is appropriate to analyze this with a multilevel (random effects / mixed effects / hierarchical, they go by several names) model, with a binary outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to CrossValidated.

You have measurements which are nested within individuals. It is appropriate to analyze this with a multilevel (random effects / mixed effects / hierarchical, they go by several names) model, with a binary outcome.

If the results are highly correlated - that is, if almost all of your subjects got the same score in the pre-test, you can safely ignore one of them (you lose a little information, but not much).

Comment: That's what i was thinking as well! thanks for your response. I am not sure if you area a Stata user, however, can you let me know if this code looks correct?

melogit most_class time || obs_hw_uic

where most_class is the test result (0/1)
time is the before and after (0/1)
obs_he_uic is the subject id number

Comment: It's a while since I've used Stata - don't you need a colon after obs_hw_uic?

Comment: looks right apart from that.

Comment: yes, I added the semi-colon. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: Colon, not semi colon.